# Adding multiple custom views inside Layout programmatically using multi lines if required

Tags: android, layout, view

In Java, building an Android app, I need to create one or more custom views and insert them in a Layout.

Each view can have different width. The heigh is always the same. I would like to place each view side by side and if the right border of the screen is reached, the next one must go to a new line.

In fact, imagine that each view represents a word, all the words are a paragraph. So all my custom view must be placed like the words, side by side and line by line.

Is there a way to do this easily with any existing Android object ?

Comment: Did you try using `ChipGroup` and `Chip`?

Comment: No, I didn't know that component. Apparently it allows to use multi lines, but is it possible to create severals views on one line if there is enough room, and use multiples lines too ? If yes, maybe that component can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `ChipGroup` and `Chip`. I think it will meet your requirements.
At first add `ChipGroup` in your view xml like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
    android:id="@+id/cgWords"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Then, to dynamically add `Chip` in this, sample code can be as following:

```
private void showTags(List<String> words) {
    for (String word : words) {
        Chip chip = new Chip(context);
        chip.setText(word);
        ChipGroup cgWords = findViewById(R.id.cgWords);
        cgWords.addView(chip);
    }
}
```

This is a screenshot after running a sample code:

[image]

Comment: Thx, it's exactly what I'm looking for !